# mysql: need code for search data

Tags: mysql

i need some code for search some data inside DB...
i have two fields that is `id` and `name`...
if i type "ABC" it can show all data about "ABC"..
if "DEF"=>all DEF data...or i type anything it can show that "anything"...

i'm just know how to show all data inside fields that makes "ABC" and "DEF" show together,the code like this:

```
"SELECT ID,Name FROM Regist ORDER BY date";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL wildcards: `_` AND `%` (in conjunction with keyword `LIKE`)

---

**`_` denotes a single character**

```
SELECT name FROM colors WHERE name LIKE 'gr_y';
```

**Output**: 'grAy', 'grEy'.

---

**`%` denotes any number of characters**

```
SELECT name FROM colors WHERE name LIKE 'gr%';
```

**Output**: 'grAY', 'grEY', 'grEEN'.

---

**You can use both `_` and `%` multiple times**

```
SELECT name FROM color WHERE name LIKE '_ra%';
```

**Output**: 'GraY', 'OraNGE'.

---

In your case, if you want to list the names containing starting with either 'ABC' or 'DEF', your query would be like this:

```
SELECT id,name FROM Regist
    WHERE name LIKE 'ABC%' OR name LIKE 'DEF%'
    ORDER BY date
```

If you want your names to contain the strings 'ABC' OR 'DEF' anywhere inside, your query would be:

```
SELECT id,name FROM Regist
    WHERE name LIKE '%ABC%' OR name LIKE '%DEF%'
    ORDER BY date
```

Finally, if you want your names to contain both 'ABC' AND 'DEF' you could use:

```
SELECT id,name FROM Regist
    WHERE name LIKE '%ABC%DEF%' OR name LIKE '%DEF%ABC%'
    ORDER BY date
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want something like this:

```
SELECT id,name FROM Regist WHERE NAME LIKE '%ABC%' OR NAME LIKE '%DEF%';
```

Please note that this kind of search is inefficient and if you need something like that you'd better use something like [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/)

Comment: how if i want everything which i have been input can show..??but just only for that data...

Answer (score 0):

From the little i understand your question

```
"SELECT ID,Name FROM Regist where name='ABC' ORDER BY date";
```

Answer (score 0):

is this correct?

```
"SELECT id,name FROM Regist WHERE id LIKE '%' OR NAME LIKE '%' ORDER BY date";
```